# Adding a Word to New Custom Dictionary Spell Check Still Fails

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016, spell-check

I have added a custom dictionary and added the Word "dialing" to it. Please see the screen shot below where this shows:

[image: dictionary list]

[image: word added to dictionary]

The spelling still doesn't get picked up when I open the a new appointment and set up a Teams Meeting.

[image]

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is to get this to work in my Outlook and then I need to find a way to deploy this to all the staff as they all require this spelling to not be marked as incorrect.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In British English, dialling has 2 L's, only the US uses a single L, so it's prioritising your default language choice [as opposed to prioritizing it ;)

Comment: We use British English, but I have been tasked with getting the American spelling to be accepted on every computer. Do you know how I get it to override any other spelling for that one word?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

As I know, you may select to edit the word list of "CUSTOM.DIC" and add "dialing" to the list to see if it works.

Comment: Hi, sorry, that doesn't work. I have updated to the latest version and made sure that "dialing" is in CUSTOM.DIC, but it still picks up the spelling as incorrect.

Comment: Sorry that I have not found more possible workarounds about your situation so far.